# Windows forms timer not waiting for method to return

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, timer, system.io.file

I'm having a problem with my windows forms timer, which is supposed call a method that reads data from serial using Serial.ReadExisting().
I often get multiple calls from the timer when my com port is attempting to send data over, which breaks a single string into multiple strings.
This bothers me, as I put a timestamp in front of the returning string and append it to a multiline textbox.
Is there any way for the timer to wait until the method has finished reading the incoming data without having to delay/slow down my timer?

What I have so far:

```
private void loop_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddToTextBox(Program.SerialReadLine());
}
```

And

```
public static string SerialReadLine()
{
    string read = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
    return read;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the timer, do the call and enable it again.

```
private void loop_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loop.Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        AddToTextBox(Program.SerialReadLine());
    }
    finally
    {
        loop.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: alternatively use while (true) { } in a new thread with sleep between the calls. The Problem with the timer Stop(), Start() Solution is that if you cancel the timer from outside it will still finish its loop and start again. so what im doing from outside is: loop = null. Then your finally { loop?.enabled = true; } wont accidently restart the timer.

Comment: How can i safely call methods from other threads?
Any examples?